# Allow a two specific phrase and continue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegEx originally like this:

```
/https:\/\/medal.tv\/games\euro-truck-sim-2\/clips\/([A-z0-9-]+)(\/[A-z0-9]+)?(\??[A-z0-9]+\=?[A-z0-9]+-[A-z0-9]+)?/
```

which works perfectly, however, I would like it to work both when it is "euro-truck-sim-2" and "imported-clips". I have not too much (practically, zero) experience with RegEx and I have no clue what I am doing wrong. This is what I tried and I don't know if the RegEx or something else is broken with the code itself.

```
/https:\/\/medal.tv\/games\/(imported-clips|euro-truck-sim-2+)?\/clips\/([A-z0-9-]+)(\/[A-z0-9]+)?(\??[A-z0-9]+\=?[A-z0-9]+-[A-z0-9]+)?/
```

What I see is that after the imported-clips match, there is nothing else after that in my link:

```
https://medal.tv/clips/imported-clips
```

Expected behavior should be:

```
https://medal.tv/games/imported-clips/clips/remglmZK54/egmkr4t
```

or

```
https://medal.tv/games/euro-truck-sim-2/clips/remglmZK54/egmkr4t
```

changed into

```
https://medal.tv/clips/remglmZK54
```

Comment: You don't need `+` after `euro-truck-sim-2`, unless you also want to match `euro-truck-sim-22`, `euro-truck-sim-222`, etc. And the `?` after the group will allow you to leave this part blank.

Comment: What do you mean by "after the match"? How are you using the regexp? Please show the code. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Better add input text and expected output for clarity, and reproductible sample.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, the code doesn't really help here and that's why I wanted to ask if this is an issue with my RegEx. This is JS

Comment: It looks like you're doing a match/replace, but what's your replacement pattern?

Comment: The second Regex you provided isn't great, but it matches as you expected. ([see](https://regex101.com/r/5oixCH/2)). The problem is with your replacement pattern/code, not the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found the solution:
>
> ```
> /https:\/\/medal.tv\/games\/(?:imported-clips|euro-truck-sim-2)\/clips\/([A-z0-9-]+)(\/[A-z0-9]+)?(\??[A-z0-9]+\=?[A-z0-9]+-[A-z0-9]+)?/
> ```

Reconsider the `A-z`, as this will not produce the result you're expecting.

The range is code-points *0x41 – 0x7a*, which includes the values between *Z* and *a*.

- *[Wikipedia – ASCII – Printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)*

I suggest using *"case-insensitive"* mode `i`, and adjusting the ranges to `a-z`.

Additionally,

- escape the `.` in *"medal.tv"*
- replace the `0-9` with `\d`
- and un-escape the `=`

```
/https:\/\/medal\.tv\/games\/(?:imported-clips|euro-truck-sim-2)\/clips\/([a-z\d-]+)(\/[a-z\d]+)?(\??[a-z\d]+=?[a-z\d]+-[a-z\d]+)?/gi
```

```js
var s = `https://medal.tv/games/imported-clips/clips/remglmZK54/egmkr4t
https://medal.tv/games/euro-truck-sim-2/clips/remglmZK54/egmkr4t`
var p = /https:\/\/medal\.tv\/games\/(?:imported-clips|euro-truck-sim-2)\/clips\/([a-z\d-]+)(\/[a-z\d]+)?(\??[a-z\d]+=?[a-z\d]+-[a-z\d]+)?/gi
console.log([...s.matchAll(p)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to match certain parts of the string with a regular expression and to remove them with [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
const str1 = 'https://medal.tv/games/imported-clips/clips/remglmZK54/egmkr4t';
const str2 = 'https://medal.tv/games/euro-truck-sim-2/clips/remglmZK54/egmkr4t';

let re =
  /(?<=https:\/\/medal.tv\/)games\/(imported-clips|euro-truck-sim-2)\/(?=clips\/[A-z0-9]+)|\/[A-z0-9]+$/g;

let out1 = str1.replace(re, '');
console.log(out1)

let out2 = str2.replace(re, '');
console.log(out2)
```

prints

```
https://medal.tv/clips/remglmZK54
https://medal.tv/clips/remglmZK54
```

Explanation:

1. Use [lookbehind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Lookbehind_assertion) `(?<=)` and [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Lookahead_assertion) `(?=)` to match the prefix string `https://medal.tv/` and the suffix string`clips/remglmZK54`, respectively. This is because we want to anchor the middle part of the string and still keep the prefix and suffix in the final result.
2. The part of `games/imported-clips/` or `games/euro-truck-sim-2` is to be matched and replaced by empty string `''`, hence the usage of `games\/(imported-clips|euro-truck-sim-2)\/`. `( ... | ... )` denotes logical [`OR`](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation).
3. We also need to remove the ending alphanumeric characters `egmkr4t` (excluding underscore `_`) as well as the last `/`, which is handled by `\/[A-z0-9]+$` and the global modifier `g`.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for the oversimplified answer. I have added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
/https:\/\/medal.tv\/games\/(?:imported-clips|euro-truck-sim-2)\/clips\/([A-z0-9-]+)(\/[A-z0-9]+)?(\??[A-z0-9]+\=?[A-z0-9]+-[A-z0-9]+)?/
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong in the original code and how you fixed it.